# swipe show navigation "dots"

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

New to your forum - please excuse any misteps.
Using a swipe show/slide show. The show works, but the "dots" below the show, which should follow as the user swipes don't. I have tried adding an "a" tag within the list item, also tried a span with a class "on".

## HTML

```
<div class="dots">
    <ul id='position'>
        <li class='on'></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.dots {
    margin: 7px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 680px;
}
.dots a {
    color: rgb(205, 205, 205) !important;
    font-style: normal;
}
.dots #position {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dots #position li {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 0px 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px grey, 0px 0px 1px 1px #8b8989;
}
.dots #position li.on {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px -1px #7EC153, 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: rgb(126, 193, 83);
}
```

---

Live site demo: `http://192.185.168.157/~rylex658/mobile/residential-cabinets.html`

Comment: Swipe? Like for mobile development and allowing a user to `slide` their finger to rotate the slideshow...?

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel Yes, the finger swipes to progress the slide show. The dots under the show are supposed to match the image in view, and allow the user to move the slide show, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Author of Swipeshow here.

`.dots #position` should be `.dots#position` -- try it out. Also, there's no need to populate it with `<li>`'s -- they will be done for you by the library.